# The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version

Tags: azure-devops

I get an error like this while i run a pipeline in azure-dev-ops. I am using visual studio 2022 in my development machine and targeting .net framework 6.0

This is the portion of YAML file for vs-build and i have selected 17.0 which i assume points to vs-2022.

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vsVersion: 17.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

The error and warning are as follows. However **this runs first class from my visual studio 2022 and publishes to azure also**. However the problem is in the pipeline from azure devops.

The error is:

[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

The warning is:

##[warning]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.

```
(some portions edited)

2022-12-19T05:11:10.1067688Z ##[section]Starting: Build solution **\*.sln
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1232474Z ==============================================================================
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1232945Z Task         : Visual Studio build
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1233282Z Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1234112Z Version      : 1.212.0
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1234354Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1234775Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
2022-12-19T05:11:10.1235216Z ==============================================================================
2022-12-19T05:11:12.3795334Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers-v3\tools\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json
2022-12-19T05:11:12.5152625Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers-v3\tools\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
2022-12-19T05:11:12.5882524Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers-v3\tools\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
2022-12-19T05:11:13.0816169Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers-v3\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=1eb4908b-1929-48af-9129-604bd23cf8b4|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.212.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-msbuildhelpers-v3\tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="D:\a\_temp\WebAppContent\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_9db02ed4-da57-41f4-952f-5942d75c0ac2_build_4_0"
2022-12-19T05:11:13.2601162Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
2022-12-19T05:11:13.3324607Z Build started 12/19/2022 5:11:13 AM.
2022-12-19T05:11:13.6294719Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2022-12-19T05:11:13.6304392Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2022-12-19T05:11:13.6305410Z   Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2022-12-19T05:11:14.4624789Z **##[warning]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
2022-12-19T05:11:14.4638167Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (1) is building** "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2022-12-19T05:11:14.4639912Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:14.5033435Z PrepareForBuild:
2022-12-19T05:11:14.5034071Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:14.5038573Z   Creating directory "obj\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:14.5056631Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\obj\Release\net6.0\ref\".
2022-12-19T05:11:14.5057940Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\ref".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1252082Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1257097Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (2) is building "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (3:2) on node 1 (default targets).
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1258265Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1265444Z PrepareForBuild:
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1266113Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1269965Z   Creating directory "obj\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1272712Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\obj\Release\net6.0\ref\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1273636Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\ref".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1920509Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1922575Z Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (3:2) is building "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj" (4:3) on node 1 (default targets).
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1924372Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1925911Z PrepareForBuild:
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1926547Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1940432Z   Creating directory "obj\Release\net6.0\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1943387Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\ref\".
2022-12-19T05:11:15.1944779Z   Creating directory "bin\Release\net6.0\ref".
2022-12-19T05:11:16.7863111Z CoreCompile:
2022-12-19T05:11:16.8091409Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /highentropyva+ /nullable:enable Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\ref\net6.0\WindowsBase.dll" /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.dll /refout:obj\Release\net6.0\ref\BlazorAppDB.Shared.dll /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /analyzerconfig:obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzerconfig:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config\analysislevel_6_default.editorconfig" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\securitycodescan.vs2019\5.6.7\analyzers\dotnet\SecurityCodeScan.VS2019.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\securitycodescan.vs2019\5.6.7\analyzers\dotnet\YamlDotNet.dll /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll" Models\Audit.cs Models\Businessgroup.cs Models\DataPrivacyInfo.cs Models\LookupTable.cs Models\ProcurementInfo.cs Models\Questionnaire.cs Models\RequestInfo.cs Models\RiskMasterDatum.cs Models\RiskTransactionDatum.cs Models\Sampleusertable.cs Models\SupplierInfo.cs Models\UserTable.cs Models\WorkflowTable.cs WeatherForecast.cs obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs "obj\Release\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0149504Z ##[warning]CSC(0,0): Warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0157174Z CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0238610Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0243568Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0252217Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0255496Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0261694Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0264957Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0269061Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0272593Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0278476Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0281483Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0285993Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0288417Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0293110Z ##[error]BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): Error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0296042Z D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0297467Z   CompilerServer: server - server processed compilation - 79980192-554b-4ebc-9d42-6f90cd2b1098
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0445938Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0484681Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0519518Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0531486Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0596890Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0599096Z Build FAILED.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0677313Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0678525Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0679957Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0681095Z (_WarnWhenUsingNET6AndVSPriorTo17 target) -> 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0682459Z   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0683182Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0683283Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0684247Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0684794Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0685540Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0686724Z   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0687336Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0687448Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0687776Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0688284Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0689463Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0690114Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0691097Z   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0691709Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0691802Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0692131Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0692640Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0693251Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0694301Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0694812Z (CoreCompile target) -> 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0696142Z   CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.JsonSourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.5\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0697409Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0697504Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0697835Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0698352Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Server\BlazorAppDB.Server.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0699475Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Client\BlazorAppDB.Client.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0700132Z "D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0700612Z (CoreCompile target) -> 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0701528Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0702988Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0704979Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0707784Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0710617Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0713116Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0716239Z   D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\obj\Release\net6.0\BlazorAppDB.Shared.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): error CS8652: The feature 'global using directive' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version. [D:\a\1\s\BlazorAppDB\Shared\BlazorAppDB.Shared.csproj]
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0717516Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0718046Z     4 Warning(s)
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0718589Z     7 Error(s)
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0719350Z 
2022-12-19T05:11:21.0719889Z Time Elapsed 00:00:07.72
2022-12-19T05:11:21.1911708Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
2022-12-19T05:11:21.2985457Z ##[section]Finishing: Build solution **\*.sln
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the log, it is still using the visual studio 2019.

```
2022-12-19T05:11:13.0816169Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
```

It seems you are using the Windows 2019 agent. If you enable the system.debug variable (set the value to “true”), you will see this warning `##[warning]Visual Studio version '17.0' not found. Falling back to version '16.0'` when you choose `vsVersion: 17.0` in the VSBuild task.

Please try to use the windows 2022 agent (windows-latest) and see if it works. You can check the software list of windows agent [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/tree/main/images/windows) .

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
```

Comment: *Windows 2019*
*windows 2022*
You mean VS?

Comment: Hi @AntikM, that is not the VS version. It is the windows version of [Microsoft hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) .